# JQuery and CKeditor Stopped loading on Drupal 7 Admin Node Edit Pages

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

The Jquery UI or Ajax seemed to stop loading on my admin pages and update pages. CKeditor no longer loads and the progress bar on the update page won't show anymore. It used to work. I disabled all of my modules and it still doesn't work. I have like 10 websites on the same Drupal install and they all work except mine... I have attached some images for reference.[No Ckeditor On Edit Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi2fR.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated Jquery Update module?

Go to modules, find Jquery Update, click Configure and check version of jQuery for admin pages. If it's set to be the same version as for front end, try to set it to 1.5 version an check editor again.

Hope this is a problem.